# Access HomePageComponent via SOQL or Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, home-page-component, custom-link, home-page-layout

Outside of using the SOAP API (and Metaforce), is there any way to access HomePageComponents and which WebLink records are in each?  Even better would be finding a way to access the Home Page Layout assigned to a profile.

Is there a way to get this information in Apex/VisualForce/Lightning?

The goal is to recreate the sidebar in a Custom Component at the bottom of a Console so that switching apps preserves the links that users see without having redundant logic

Comment: What's the end goal here?

Comment: The end goal is to recreate the sidebar in a custom component at the bottom of a Console so that switching apps preserves the links that users see.